# Whenever gem doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backup, cron, whenever

I'm trying to make an automated backup system for my rails databases using the `backup` and `whenever` gem. I can successfully generate a config file for this and I can also run the backup (the backup gets stored on an Amazon server).

For some reason my `whenever` gem doesn't seem to work properly. Every minute it should perform the backup command but for some reason it doesn't. When I perform the command manually it works though.

This is my schedule.rb file

`every 1.minute do
  command "backup perform -t db_backup"
end`

My crontab config also seems to be good because `crontab -l` gives this:

#Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/roy/Backup/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t db_backup'

#End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/roy/Backup/config/schedule.rb

Does someone know what my problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your `crontab` by following command

```
 crontab -r
```

Then update your `crontab` again

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

If you use `Capistrano` deployment you should have the following configuration in `deploy.rb` file

```
set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:rails_env)}" }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me sadly, even the backup.log file doesn't log anything (like an error or something).

Comment: You can look into the cron.log, you may find any hints.

Comment: You may want to restart your cron service as well `service cron restart`